# Joining data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm working on the adventureworks example database.

I have a table with employee's, which all have a certain manager. So in the table employee's there is a column ManagerID.

Also in the table employee there's a ContactID, which contains the name of that employee.

I would like to have a list with all the managers and their names. How can I pull this off?

The table looks something like

```
EmployeeID  ContactID  ManagerID
----------  ---------  ---------
    1           21         4
    2           24         4
    3           32         7
    4           34         2
    5           35         2
    6           42         7
    7           44         4
```

So i'll need a DISTINCT list of the managerID, and then search for each managerID their appropreate ContactID.

So: 
manager of employee 1 is Employee 4 with the ContactID 34.
manager of employee 3 is Employee 7 with the ContactID 44.
manager of employee 4 is Employee 2 with the ContactID 24.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it joining the table `myTable` with itself matching manager_id's with employee_id's

```
select 
    t.employeeid as employee_id, 
    t.manager_id as manager_id, 
    t2.contact_id as manager_contact_id 
from mytable t left outer join mytable t2 on t.managerid = t2.employeeid
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, ConactID
FROM ´yourtable´
GROUP BY ManagerID
```

There you get the grouped data.
If you want to have Managers listed as well you have to JOIN the data again (self-join)

Comment: This still gives the ContactID of the Employee, and not of it's manager